# Can access SSH but can't access cPanel web server

Tags: centos

I've built a Cent OS 6.0 vps and then i've installed the latest cPanel/WHM.

This isn't my first installation but i've noticed something weird especially that i've never used the 6.0 version.. when i tried to install cPanel, it didn't recognize `wget` so installed it, then cPanel said that Perl isn't installed, i've installed that and the installation went well since then.

Now, when i've tried to access the server via the browser with the IP Adress as i've used to, it didn't work, it was just loading forever, i tried the `2087` port, still the same. but SSH works.

I've also tried the commands to start the server manually but none of them worked.

How to fix that?

### Edit: `iptables -nL` *Result*

```
root@server [~]# iptables -nL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
acctboth   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
acctboth   all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain acctboth (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           tcp  --  216.119.149.168      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            216.119.149.168     tcp spt:80
           tcp  --  216.119.149.168      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            216.119.149.168     tcp spt:25
           tcp  --  216.119.149.168      0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            216.119.149.168     tcp spt:110
           icmp --  216.119.149.168      0.0.0.0/0
           icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            216.119.149.168
           tcp  --  216.119.149.168      0.0.0.0/0
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            216.119.149.168
           udp  --  216.119.149.168      0.0.0.0/0
           udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            216.119.149.168
           all  --  216.119.149.168      0.0.0.0/0
           all  --  0.0.0.0/0            216.119.149.168
           all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: "Loading forever" sounds like a firewall issue. May you update your question to include the output of the following command: **iptables -nL**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some future headaches and just connect to your cpanel instance by ssh tunneling into your server.

> ssh -L 9999:localhost:2087 myhostfoo.com

then setup your web browser to use localhost:9999 as a SOCK5 proxy.

I haven't had my morning coffee, but it looks like @VladimirBlaskov is correct: your input chain is blocking all inbound traffic, and you don't have a rule explicitly allowing 2087 TCP.

Comment: I'm not sure if undestand you correctly, but that doesn't only apply for the 2087, Port 80 and 25 can't be accessed by the public.

Comment: @Tom your firewall allows any ip (0.0.0.0/0) to connect to 216.119.149.168 on ports 22,25,80,110 TCP. You have no rule allowing port 2087 TCP, and as such, iptables (your firewall) is blocking cpanel sessions. You either need to allow traffic through your firewall, or, alternatively, ssh tunnel into your server and connect to cPanel via localhost.

Answer (score -3):

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

that should sort you :-)

Comment: Is totally disabling the firewall really a good idea?

Comment: Totally disabling the firewall is a terrible idea.